# scatter plot - mark absolute size from data and custom colormap

Tags: pgfplots, size, mark

I'm trying to implement a scatter plot that automatically scales the marks according to its absolute values. I don't want to use `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` but rather `\pgfplotspointmeta`, as I need to compare it to another plot, though I just can't manage to do so...

Furthermore I tried creating a colormap, that maps from a color range for z > 0, and a different color range for z < 0. So you'd immediately notice whether a value is negative or positive - though I'm kind of confused so set the limits the way, that it changes from red to blue at 0, because I'm already using the meta data for the size...

```
\pgfplotstableread{
    A B C
    0    5 -10
    0.5  2   0
    1    7   5  
    1.5 11  20
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={test}{[2pt]
        rgb255(0pt)=(255, 200, 0);
        rgb255(500pt)=(255, 75, 0);
        rgb255(502pt)=(0, 100, 255);
        rgb255(1000pt)=(0, 255, 255)
    }
}

\begin{axis}[
colorbar 
]

\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
scatter src=explicit,
mark=*,
scatter/use mapped color={
    draw=mapped color,
    fill=mapped color,
},
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style=
{/tikz/mark size={.6pt+abs(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/200)}}]
table[meta expr=abs(\thisrow{C})] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd be happy for hints
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I have understood your question right. Do you mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={test}{[2pt]
            rgb255(0pt)=(255, 200, 0);
            rgb255(500pt)=(255, 75, 0);
            rgb255(502pt)=(0, 100, 255);
            rgb255(1000pt)=(0, 255, 255)
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colorbar,
        % because you want the color change at zero but don't have "symmetric"
        % data, you have to give the `point meta min' and `point meta max'
        % values manually
        point meta min=-20,
        point meta max=20,
    ]
        \addplot[
            scatter,
            only marks,
            scatter src=explicit,
            mark=*,
            scatter/use mapped color={
                draw=mapped color,
                fill=mapped color,
            },
            % store the (original) of "C" in a macro ...
            visualization depends on={\thisrow{C} \as \perpointmarksize},
            scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
                % ... and use this macro here
                % (please note that I have changed the values a bit )
                /tikz/mark size={1pt+abs(\perpointmarksize/5)}
            },
        % because of a bug in PGFPlots (<https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/>)
        % you have to give the table explicitly like here or in a file to not get an
        % error message
        % (it is not allowed to give the table as a command)
        ] table [meta=C] {
            A B C
            0    5 -10
            0.5  2   0
            1    7   5
            1.5 11  20
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]