# How to make dot scatter plot with labels in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How would I make a graph like this? Specifically with the labels.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Maybe this can help as starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86631/47927

Comment: ... together with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376758/95441 for scatter color and marker sizes